# How to "follow" the references / memory profile of specific Javascript values, or how to tie references in memory profiler to source code

Tags: javascript, debugging, memory, memory-leaks

I'd like to know if it's possible (with any browser / dev tools) to pick a specific value or closure variable while debugging and "follow" or "watch" it somehow into future execution points on the page. Basically, a memory profiler attached to just a single value, which would show during debugging or snapshots whether that value is still being retained either directly or indirectly. Alternatively, I'd like to know if it's possible to look at references in the memory profiler/snapshot view in, say, Chrome, and tie those references to actual points in the source code.

My problem is that I am debugging a memory leak caused by rebuilding a DOM tree for a portion of a fairly complex page. Even taking a very controlled memory snapshot that just looks at a single redraw (removing the old DOM tree and adding a new one, where I know that I'm  unintentionally retaining a reference to a small part of the old one), there are still hundreds of objects to look through, and to be quite honest I find the memory profiler in Chrome to be very confusing to navigate through. And even when I find references that might be of interest, I'm at a loss as to how to tie them to points in the code - it's great to know that I'm retaining an HTMLDivElement somewhere but that could be almost any of the files...

So basically, I'm unsure how to proceed, and the two solutions I'm asking about are the only things I can think of, if there is any way to do them. Sorry that this is such a vague question, I am open to other ways of tackling this as well.

Comment: I am a bit rusty on this topic but if I remember correctly the triggers for the garbage collector aren't strictly enforced by any standard, making memory tracking a bit of a hit and miss. Again, to my recollection, reloading the whole page will cause everything to be cleared and collected, so that's always a last resort solution. Then again I might be wrong: as said, I am a bit rusty... Is this leak something that big as to be considered a problem?